# How to do multiple lines in GoogleMaps marker snippet in Swift?

Tags: swift, google-maps

Let says I have this code

`//time and speed are strings
    marker.snippet = time + speed // 2016/04/14 60kmph`

I want them to show in two lines and not one line only
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hahaha, "\n" LOL???

"\n" should get parsed as a standard new line.

So result would be this?

```
marker.snippet = time + "\n" + speed
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with

```
 marker.snippet = " \(time) \n \(speed)"
```

All the best